# Сервант как остекленная секция стенки

Tags: значение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли назвать одну из секций стенки сервантом (или буфетом): речь идет об остекленной секции, хранящей в данном случае посуду вместе с различными сувенирами. Определяется ли сервант содержанием или техническим исполнением? Может ли он быть составной частью?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту вертикальную (сверху донизу) секцию шкафа можно назвать *буфетом*. Как разновидность буфета это "буфет с нишей". *Сервантом* называют другую, низкую разновидность буфета: http://tovarslovar.ru/610byfet.html
Тип конструкции, подобной застеклённому верхнему шкафчику буфета, иногда называют "витриной"; в современной торговле мебелью встречаются и отдельные предметы под названием "шкаф-витрина".